# How to find all open PowerPoint instances C#

Tags: c#

I'm running integration tests and every time I finish a test I want to close out of all instances of PowerPoint. Currently my code seems to only find the current PowerPoint process and closes out of it however in some cases I may have 2 or 3 PowerPoints open and would like to close out of them all.

My code is as follows

Any ideas on why it only ever thinks there is one instance of PowerPoint open?

```
   private static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> PowerPointSession;

 var capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.SetCapability("app", "Root");
            PowerPointSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(AppDriverUrl), capabilities);
            PowerPointSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

for closing out of PowerPoint

```
public static void TearDown()
{
    var pro = Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT");

    foreach (var item in pro)
    {
        if (PowerPointSession == null) return;
        // Restore original mode before closing down
        PowerPointSession.FindElementByName("Close").Click();
        PowerPointSession.FindElementByName("Don't Save").Click();

        PowerPointSession.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: You're not referencing the process in the loop, would expect something like `item.Kill()`

Comment: In your code you work with just one `PowerPointSession` (whatever that is), so you close this same session multiple times, because you don't assign it anywhere in code provided.

Comment: @stuartd I see what you are saying and I do need to use item.kill in my foreach however for some reason `foreach (var item in pro)` has a count of one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not saving anything already done there you can terminate it like:

```
var p = Process.Start("taskkill", "/im POWERPNT.exe /f");
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)